# sql server stored proc returns only one row

Tags: stored-procedures, spring-batch

I have an issue where only the last record in a csv file is written to the database by my stored procedure. I thought this might be related to the type of file (csv or text) because I have a comma delimited text file with only five records that will write all records, but when I used a csv file only the last record is written. I did read a post which said that this could be related to using a scalar variable in the stored proc but I don't think that this is right because when I use the text file it's still the same stored proc. Please advise.

Thanks!

here's the stored proc:
USE [SomeDB]
GO

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SaveUser]    Script Date: 8/1/2016 9:25:24 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveUser]
          -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
          @PartnerID INT,
          @SourceID INT,
          @OrgSourcedIDs NVARCHAR(50),
          @Role NVARCHAR(50),
          @UserID NVARCHAR(50),
          @GivenName NVARCHAR(50),
          @FamilyName NVARCHAR(50),
          @Email NVARCHAR(50),
          @Grade NVARCHAR(50),
          @Identifier NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
          -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
          -- interfering with SELECT statements.
          SET NOCOUNT ON;
          DECLARE @ReturnVal NVARCHAR(10)

          DECLARE @IsTransfer Bit = 0
          DECLARE @IsUpdate BIT = 0

          SELECT @IsTransfer =  CASE WHEN OrgSourcedIDs != @OrgSourcedIDs THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                            @IsUpdate =  CASE WHEN HASHBYTES('SHA', GivenName +FamilyName +Email +Grade ) != HASHBYTES('SHA', @GivenName + @FamilyName + @Email + @Grade ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          FROM dbo.tblUsers a
          WHERE a.PartnerID = @PartnerID AND a.SourcedID = @SourceID
          IF @@RowCount = 0
          BEGIN
                         -- If not, add it to staging table with ACTION = INSERT (into tblUser)
                         INSERT INTO dbo.tblUsers
                                       ( PartnerID, SourcedID, OrgSourcedIDs, Role, UserID,
                                       GivenName, FamilyName, Email, Grade, Identifier,
                                       Action )
                         VALUES
                                       ( @PartnerID, @SourceID, @OrgSourcedIDs, @Role, @UserID,
                                       @GivenName, @FamilyName, @Email, @Grade, @Identifier,
                                       'Create' )
                         --SELECT @ReturnVal = 'INSERT'
          END
          ELSE IF (@IsTransfer = 1)
          BEGIN
                         UPDATE dbo.tblUsers
                                       SET
                                                      OrgSourcedIDs = @OrgSourcedIDs,
                                                      UserID = @UserID,
                                                      GivenName = @GivenName,
                                                      FamilyName = @FamilyName,
                                                      Email = @Email,
                                                      Grade = @Grade,
                                                      Identifier = @Identifier,
                                                      Action = 'Transfer'
                                       WHERE
                                                      PartnerID = @PartnerID
                                                      AND SourcedID = @SourceID

          END
          ELSE IF(@IsUpdate = 1)
          BEGIN
                                       UPDATE dbo.tblUsers
                                       SET
                                                      UserID = @UserID,
                                                      GivenName = @GivenName,
                                                      FamilyName = @FamilyName,
                                                      Email = @Email,
                                                      Grade = @Grade,
                                                      Identifier = @Identifier,
                                                      Action = 'Update'
                                       WHERE
                                                      PartnerID = @PartnerID
                                                      AND SourcedID = @SourceID
          END



          --SELECT @ReturnVal
```

END

GO

Comment: From what I can see, your stored procedure is inserting exactly one record into tblusers, or updating the table with two different sets of values.  Are you calling this stored procedure from something else that is reading the CSV file?

Comment: JaydipJ, Thanks for the response! I figured out what the problem was. I was violating a unique value constraint on the 
SourcedID column using one of those CSV File Generators by having only 3 digits in the randomly generated numbers in that column. Once I increased the number of digits to 9 for the randomly generated values in that column it was fine.